# Drupal 7 views data duplicate

Tags: drupal, view

I need to show info about my users in view. And I faced with the problem. When I establish relations and add the fields from relations nodes to user fields, I get the duplicate user outputs. How I can combine this rows ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set "`Distinct`" option in **advanced settings** in your Views administration panel. It's in "**Query parameters**" line.